# What is a unit of work in regards to database objects?

Tags: database, database-design, unit-of-work

In layman's terms, what is a unit of work in regards to database objects? I'm researching how to convert database tables into C# classes and I frequently come across this term, but everyone seems to describe it as if you should already know what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll quote [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) here, since I think his meaning is one of the clearest, most comprehensible I've seen:

> A Unit of Work keeps track of everything you do during a business transaction that can affect the database. When you're done, it figures out everything that needs to be done to alter the database as a result of your work.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it means the work required to complete an atomic action, e.g. transferring money between two checking accounts.

Example (in pseudocode)

```
Procedure TransferBetweenAccounts(Amount, Account source, Account target)
   Begin Transaction
      Debit source account By (Amount)   }----Unit of
      Credit target account By (amount)  }----Work 
   End Transaction

   If Transaction Failed
       Roll Back
```

A good MSDN article describing **Unit of Work and Persistence Ignorance** is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ to SQL a unit of work is defined as (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546187.aspx):

> An instance of a data context should
>   have a lifetime of one "unit of work."
>   In a loosely-coupled environment, a
>   unit of work is typically small,
>   perhaps one optimistic transaction,
>   including a single call to
>   SubmitChanges. Therefore, the data
>   context is created and disposed at
>   method scope. If the unit of work
>   includes calls to business rules
>   logic, then generally you will want to
>   keep the DataContext instance for that
>   whole operation

Understanding the unit of work is important for success with LINQ to SQL. Have a look at this page (A update scenario), for how the unit of work pattern fits into LINQ to SQL:

http://aspalliance.com/1414_LINQ_to_SQL_Part_4__Updating_our_Database.3

Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Architecture book has quite a few pages devoted to the topic (pg 184-194). His brief definition is:

> "Maintains a list of objects affected
>   by a business transaction and
>   coordinates the writing out of changes
>   and the resolution of concurrency
>   problems."